# Evalute $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int _{0}^{1}\frac{nf(x)}{1+n^2x^2}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Suppose $f\colon [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, Find the following limit:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int _{0}^{1}\frac{nf(x)}{1+n^2x^2}\,dx$$
I know the  answer is equal   $\frac{\pi}{2}f(0) $, but I don't prove that.

Any ideas or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $=\int_0^1 f(x)\,d\arctan(nx)\to\int_0^1 f(x)\,d\frac{\pi}2I(x>0)=\frac {\pi}2f(0)$.

Comment: @Dear A.S,would you explain your answer please

Comment: The first step is just variable change, the second is convergence in distribution and the third is evaluation of a Riemann-Stieltjes integral w.r.t. step function.

Answer (score 6):

With the change $y=nx$ you get $$\int _{0}^{1}\frac{nf(x)}{1+n^2x^2}\,dx = \int _{0}^{n}\frac{f(\frac{y}{n})}{1+y^2}\,dx.$$ Now Lebesgue theorem should allow you to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

I get that the limit is
$\frac12 (1+\pi \coth(\pi))f(0)
$.
Since this disagrees with
what is presumably the correct answer,
I would like to know
where and what my error is.

Thanks.

$\begin{array}\\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int _{0}^{1}\frac{nf(x)}{1+n^2x^2}\,dx
&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{nf(k/n)}{1+n^2(k/n)^2}
\qquad\text{(the error is probably here, but I'm not sure why)}\\
&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{f(k/n)}{1+k^2}\\
&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{0\le k\lt n^a}\frac{f(k/n)}{1+k^2}
+\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{n^a\ge k\le n-1}\frac{f(k/n)}{1+k^2}
\qquad\text{where }\frac12 < a <1\\
&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{0\le k\lt n^a}\frac{f(k/n)}{1+k^2}
\qquad\text{since }\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{n^a\le k\le n-1}\frac{f(k/n)}{1+k^2}=0\\
&=f(0)\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{0\le k\lt n^a}\frac{1}{1+k^2}\\
&=f(0)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+k^2}\\
&=\frac12 (1+\pi \coth(\pi))f(0)
\qquad\text{(according to Wolfy)}\\
&\approx 2.076674f(0)
\end{array}
$

Comment: Your mesh size is dependent on $n$. I don't think it's kosher. You basically collapsed two limiting processes into one.

Comment: Your mesh need to be $o(\frac 1 n)$ to capture changing variations of $f_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f $ is continuous at $[0,1]$ then $\forall \epsilon >0, \  \exists \delta> {0} $ such that if $|x|<\delta \ , |f(x)- f(0) |<\epsilon $. Since Continuous functions attend both maximum and minimum value on compact sets, let $M = 2\sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x) |$

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{nf(x)}{1+n^2x^2}dx= \int_{0}^{\delta} \frac{nf(x)}{1+n^2x^2}dx+\int_{\delta }^{1} \frac{n(f(x))}{1+n^2x^2}dx $$
$$= \int_{0}^{\delta} \frac{n(f(x)- f(0))}{1+n^2x^2}dx+  \int_{0}^{\delta} \frac{nf(0)}{1+n^2x^2}dx +\int_{\delta }^{1} \frac{n(f(x))}{1+n^2x^2}dx $$

$$=f(0) \arctan(n\delta)+ \int_{0}^{\delta} \frac{n(f(x)- f(0))}{1+n^2x^2}dx \int_{\delta }^{1} \frac{n(f(x))}{1+n^2x^2}dx $$

Since $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty } \arctan(x) =\frac{\pi}{2}$ then for $\epsilon>0, \ \exists \alpha  \in \mathbb{R} $ such that if $ x >\alpha $ then $|\arctan(x)- \frac{\pi}{2}| < \epsilon$ choose $N$ such that $N\delta >\alpha$ for all $n \ge N $

$$\bigg|\frac{\pi f(0)}{2}-f(0) \arctan(n\delta)- \int_{0}^{\delta} \frac{n(f(x)- f(0))}{1+n^2x^2}dx- \int_{\delta }^{1} \frac{n(f(x))}{1+n^2x^2}dx \bigg|$$

$$\le  2M\left|\frac{\pi }{2}- \arctan(n\delta) \right|+\epsilon \arctan(n\delta) < 2M\epsilon  + \epsilon^2 $$

Which implies that$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty }\int_{0}^{1} \frac{nf(x)}{1+n^2x^2}dx=\frac{\pi f(0)}{2} $