# Convergence of $\int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{x}dx$.

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

**The Problem:**

Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,+\infty)$ be a continuous function such that $f(0)=0$. Is $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{x}dx$ convergent?

---

**The Context:**

I've just come across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1679031/evalute-lim-limits-n-to-infty-int-01-fracnfx1n2x2-dx) (for a continuos function $f$, calculate $\lim_{n}\int_0^1\frac{nf(x)}{1+n^2x^2}dx$) in the special case where $f(0)=0$. My first try to was apply Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem just by multiplying and dividing by $x$. So, in order to get a convergent bound, I need  $f(x)/x$ to be convergent in $[0,1]$.

Actually, I'm not able neither to prove it, nor to disprove it. An, in order to be precise, I also have include some other extre hypothesis (such as $f\ge 0$).

---

**Some remarks:**

Of course, if $\lim_{x\to0+}f(x)/x=L>0$, the answer is clear (the integral converges).

If $\lim_{x\to0+}f(x)/x=0$, then (near $x=0$) $f(x)<x$ and we also get convergence.

So the only possibility to find a counterexample (such an $f$ for wich the integral diverges) is that $\nexists\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)/x$. But, since $f(0)=0$, this is equivalent to "$f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$".

But, as I said befor, I am not able neither to find it, nor to prove the convergence.

Comment: Let $$
f(x) = \frac{1}{{\log (x/2)}}
$$ when $0<x\leq 1$ and $f(0)=0$. This function is continuous on $[0,1]$ and the integral of $f(x)/x$ diverges.

Comment: @Gary Why $\log(x/2)$ and not simply $\log x$?

Comment: $1/\log x$ is not continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: Thanks!, I was thinking only near $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Draw a triangle with base $(\frac  1{n+1}, \frac  1 n)$ and height $\frac n {\ln n}$ for $n=2,3,...$ Combine these  to get a graph of  function $g$.  Take $f(x)=xg(x)$. This function has the desired properties.

Comment: Wonderful answer.

Comment: Duplicate found in less than a minute with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_0%5E1%20%5Cfrac%7Bf(x)%7D%7Bx%7D%20%5C%2C%20dx%24)